SQL query to retrieve column names in the public schema that are foreign keys but do not have an index
I'm working on optimizing database accesses in my PostgreSQL 15 database. I want to identify columns in tables within the public schema that are foreign keys, but do not have an index associated with them.
This information will help me prioritize adding indexes to improve query performance.
Could someone provide a PostgreSQL query that returns the table name and column name of such columns?

something to get started:
SELECT  conname AS fkey_constraint
    ,   relname AS tablename
    ,   attname AS columnname
    ,   format('CREATE INDEX idx_%s_%s_fkey ON %I.%I(%I);'
        , relname
        , attname
        , nspname
        , relname
        , attname
        ) AS index_proposal
FROM    pg_constraint
    JOIN pg_class ON  pg_class.oid = conrelid
    JOIN pg_namespace ON pg_class.relnamespace = pg_namespace.oid
    JOIN pg_attribute ON  ARRAY[pg_attribute.attnum] <@ conkey AND pg_class.oid = pg_attribute.attrelid
    LEFT JOIN pg_index ON pg_class.oid = indrelid AND ARRAY[pg_attribute.attnum] = (string_to_array(pg_index.indkey::text, ' '))::smallint[]
WHERE   contype = 'f'
AND     indexrelid IS NULL
ORDER BY relname, conname, attname;

Didn't check on version 15, but it should work on even older versions. Used it last week on version 16.

You might want to create these indexes concurrently and maybe you want to optimize the indexes with additional columns. But that depends on your usage pattern.
